# How to get notifications from website B which is iframed in website A

Tags: html, iframe

I want to know how notifications work,if I iframe a website.

For example I have website A, on this website I have an iframe with website B in it. Website B sends notifications. So if I go to www.B.com it sends me notifications, however when I go to www.A.com I want to receive the notification from website B as well (remember website B was in an iframe in website A).

So how do I get notification from website A from website B??

Thanks in advance

Comment: What type of notification exactly does website B normally give?

Comment: For example the same notifications as Facebook does. Those notifications that your are tagged in something or that someone has sent you a message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the problem had to do with the application I am using. I runned some tests and sometimes the notifications were passed through the iframe and sometimes others weren't.

I am still working on a solution for my specific application problem.